# Describing the Sample Space

Tags: probability

An bag contains three same-sized balls, two are white and one is red. You keep drawing (with replacement) till you find the red ball, what is the probability that you need to draw less than 5 times?

Is the sample space {(r),(wr),(wwr),...}? Also how would I begin this problem. I dont really see a way in which to think about it properly.

Comment: Yes the sample space is {(r),(wr),(wwr),(wwwr)} and you could work out their probabilities and add them up.  It could be faster to calculate that you you need to draw $5$ or more times, i.e. that the first four draws are white.

Comment: so assuming first four are white. In order to figure that part out multiply the probabilities of getting white four times? To get 2/3 four times in a row, so 16/81? then 1-16/81 to get the final answer?

Comment: Since you're drawing "with replacement", this becomes a geometric distribution with $p = 1/3$

Answer (score 0):

The best way to list the sample space is to draw a tree diagram and end every branch of the tree diagram the moment you come across a red ball